# How can I display images with <img src=cid: >on a web page

Tags: image, email

How can I display images with `src=cid:` on a web page?
I can create mime emails with image tags with `src:cid`
pointing to mime multiparts.
But I can't get an html web page to display an image
with `<img src=cid:....>`

Answer (score 1):

Web pages work differently from html email. In other to make a web page work, you must extract out all the images and change all the `<img src="...">` to point an image in a directory on the web server. Regular expressions may help.